# Javascript :higher order functions

Tags: javascript, callback

I am new to coding and am practising higher order functions. Given the below question:

> Write a function which will split an array into two arrays (i.e.
> partition it).
>
> It will take two parameters, the first is an array of Integer values,
> and the second will be a callback which will return a boolean. If the
> callback returns true for an element, it should be placed into the
> left array, otherwise it should be placed into the right array.
>
> Examples:
>
> - `partition([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], n => n % 2 === 0)`   should look like this: `[[2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]]`
> - `partition([-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], n => n < 0)`   should look like this: `[[-5, -4, -3, -2, -1], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]`
>
> ```
> const partition = function(arr, callback) {
>     // IMPLEMENT ME
> };
> ```

I came up with the below:

```
const array = [];
arr.filter((integers) => {
  if (integers === callback) {
    array.push(integers);
    return integers;
  }
});
};

partition([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], (n) => n % 2 === 0);
partition([-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], (n) => n < 0);
```

I am stuck and unable to understand how to use `.filter` with callback, how do I split it using the `.filter` way, can you please guide me with `.filter` method for the above question.

Comment: You shouldn't use `filter()` for this.

Comment: Where is the function definition line for your function?

Comment: You should use `forEach()`, not `filter()`.

Comment: You need to declare two arrays -- one for the elements where the callback is true, another for where the callback is false.

Comment: You need to call the callback with the current element of the `forEach()` iteration.

Comment: I'm deliberately only giving hints, not writing the code for you. The only way you can learn to code is by coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter the values which return true for the callback and collect  all other values and return a new array with the values from filtering and the other collected values.

```js
const partition = function(arr, callback) { // IMPLEMENT ME
    const array = [];
    return [
        arr.filter(value => {
            if (callback(value)) return true;
            array.push(value);
        }),
        array
    ];
};

console.log(partition([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], n => n % 2 === 0)); // [[2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]]

console.log(partition([-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], n => n < 0)); // [[-5, -4, -3, -2, -1], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: why do we need to add the return statement before array.push?

Comment: the [`return` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) ends the function. the later part works then without `else`. in short: either push (and return something [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), like [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) to prevent this item to come into the filter array) or return `true` for the filtering.

Answer (score 1):

The filter function only allows you to return an array matching a condition. Therefore, if you want to build two array with the filter function, you can use it like that:

```js
let partition = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
let evenPartition = partition.filter(x => x % 2 === 0);
let oddPartition = partition.filter(x => x % 2 !== 0);
//Even partition : [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
//Odd partition : [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

You can also use the map function:

```js
let partition = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
let finalResult=[[], []];
partition.map(x => {
   if(x % 2 === 0)
      finalResult[0].push(x);
   else
      finalResult[1].push(x);
});

//Final result: [[2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]]
```

Comment: is it a new operator `<==`?

Comment: Oups, I ma de a mistake

Comment: If you're not using the result, use `forEach()` rather than `map().

Answer (score 0):

[`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) should take a callback that returns a boolean. If the callback returns `true`, it keeps the value in the resulting array, and if it returns `false` it does not add it to the array.

If you want to continue to use filter, what you have is close to working, except for the fact that you are checking for strict equality between each element and the callback function when you should instead be calling said function with `callback(integer)`.

You also need to store the output of the filter into the second array if you want to use it.

```js
const leftArray = [];
const rightArray = arr.filter((integer) => {
  if (callback(integer)) {
    leftArray.push(integer);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
});
```

Comment: your answer is partially right, the right array :expected output: right array is missing.

Comment: @DevelopingCoder what do you mean missing?

Comment: expected output is [[2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]] for the first one, I tried yours out but am only getting one of the array right, viz. [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

Comment: I was explaining how to fix your code... this isn't the full solution

Comment: thank you so much skara9, love the explanation you provided above too, thank you for your time, one question if I may ask...why do we need to add return false statement when the condition is true?

Comment: when `callback(integer)` returns true, you don't want to add it to `rightArray`, so you return false from the filter to exclude it from the array and vice versa

Comment: ah! got ya! thank you so much!... sorry I am unable to select multiple right answers for this post :)